# How can I migrate thousands of Hive tables to a MySQL database?

Tags: hive, bigdata, sqoop

Can this be possible with a *sqoop* export script? With the script below, I can only export one table at a time.

```
$sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/db \
--username root \
--table employee \ 
--export-dir /emp/emp_data
```

What are all the options we have to export the data from a Hive table to a MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code you can use -

```
sqoop export --connect  jdbc:mysql://localhost/db  \ -- conn info
--username xx --password pass12 \ -- user and pass of mysql DB
--hcatalog-database mydb --hcatalog-table myhdfstable   \ -- hdfs table and database info
--hcatalog-partition-keys mypartcolumn --hcatalog-partition-values "PART_VAL1"   \ -- optional hdfs table and partition info
--table mymysqltable  \ -- mysql table name. you can keep same name or diffrent. columns sequence can be diffrent but data type should be compatible and greater or equal than hdfs
--m 4 \ -- number of mappers.
```

I have explained each command with comments. pls remove comments before running